# Read eVRC smart card SK by PC/SC

Tags: php, pcsc

I'm trying to use PC/SC in PHP to read the eVRC vehicle technical license from Slovakia.

I connect to the card, but when I want to find out the files with the command:
`00A4040C0A0000004564556522D3031` (A0000004564556522D3031 is AID SK), so I get result `6A8A` (File not found).

commands:

```
$context = scard_establish_context();
$readers = scard_list_readers($context);
$reader = $readers[0];
echo "Using reader: ", $reader, "\n";
$connection = scard_connect($context, $reader);
var_dump($connection);
// AID SK: A0000004564556522D3031
$CMD = "00A4040C0A0000004564556522D3031";
$res = scard_transmit($connection, $CMD);
var_dump($res);
```

result:

```
Using reader: Generic Smart Card Reader Interface 0
resource(5) of type (PC/SC Connection)
string(4) "6A82"
File not found
```

I am using XAMPP and the `php_pcsc.dll` library from `pecl.php.net/package/pcsc/0.5.1/windows` for PHP 7.4

Am I doing something wrong (wrong command)?

Thank you for the advice.

Martin

Comment: Are you using this php library: https://github.com/pcsc-for-php/pcsc ? Please clarify. Otherwise, we don't know what any of the functions you're calling are supposed to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you have relevant information such as this to include :-). Don't hide it in the comments

Comment: I don't know the library and the internals of how it communicates with the reader, but in case you are communicating in T=1 (I know some libraries force it by default) my suggestion would be starting with adding Le to your command, i.e.: $CMD = "00A4040C0A0000004564556522D303100";